# Why am I not getting all the data in the manifest?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a successfully loaded and converted model, but I also need to extract the manifest. Unfortunately, when I extract the manifest, I do not get it entirely. I need to get the entire manifest. I tried to solve the problem by recursively calling the function that receives the manifest, but in any case I did not get the manifest completely. I would like to know what is the reason why a recursively called function also does not receive a manifest and how else can this problem be solved.

```
function getManifest(getToken, urn) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const baseUrl = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com";
    const url = `${baseUrl}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/${urn}/manifest`;
    const token = typeof getToken == "function" ? await getToken() : getToken;

    const fetch = () =>
      request(
        {
          url,
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
          json: true,
        },
        async (err, response, body) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }

          if (body && body.errors) {
            return reject(body.errors);
          }

          if (body.progress !== "complete") {
            await require("util").promisify(setTimeout)(3000);
            return fetch();
          }

          if ([200, 201, 202].indexOf(response.statusCode) < 0) {
            return reject(response);
          }

          return resolve(body || {});
        },
      );

    return fetch();
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a translation job is posted, it takes time(depends on file size) for translation to be complete.

If you want to get manifest as soon as the translation is 100% complete, use this [webhook api](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/extraction.finished/) and mention workflowid in post job like shown [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#example-5).

For webhook url in development mode you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it is intended for POST requests, and a GET request is used to get the manifest. I need to get a manifest only when it is completely ready, how can I do this?

Comment: Your webhook url will be called when the manifest is ready.
you should have the webhook url api running, in that api, you can call manifest api.

Comment: Where can I find sample code? The link that you gave me works during file upload.

Comment: sorry for late reply, here is the sample code: https://github.com/libvarun/DA-Sample-with-Viewer/blob/master/routes/DesignAutomation.js#L618
Please ignore the design automation part.